# Azure Table Storage - Query Where return other data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm not sure why, but I'm querying database with predicate `City` = `London` but I'm receiving entities with different values

Here's my data model:

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{

    public MyEntity()
    {
    }

    public MyEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey) : base(partitionKey, rowKey)
    {
    }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

My query:

```
var query = new TableQuery<KomisEntity>()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("City", QueryComparisons.Equal, "London"))
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Year", QueryComparisons.Equal, "2000"));

var data = await LoadWhereAsync(table, query);
```

Helper method:

```
private static async Task<List<T>> LoadWhereAsync<T>(CloudTable table, TableQuery<T> query) where T : TableEntity, new()
{
    var entities = new List<T>();


    TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    do
    {
        var page = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
        continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
        entities.AddRange(page);
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);

    return entities;
}
```

But for some reason I'm receiving entities e.g with:

`City: 'South Pierceberg'`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your query filter:

```
var query = new TableQuery<KomisEntity>()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("City", QueryComparisons.Equal, "London"))
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Year", QueryComparisons.Equal, "2000"));
```

This should generate an `or` filter like this `city==London or Year==2000`.

You can try the code below, which uses `and` filter:

```
string filter = "(City eq 'London') and (Year eq '2000')";
var query = new TableQuery<KomisEntity>().Where(filter);
```

or use this query format:

```
var query = new TableQuery<KomisEntity>().Where(
                        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("City", QueryComparisons.Equal, "London"),
                            TableOperators.And,
                            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Year", QueryComparisons.Equal, "2000")
                            )
                    );
```